# Solve the inequality $\frac{2}{x} > 3 x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I've been slowly losing my mind on how to do this question, any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Solve the inequality $$\frac{2}{x} > 3 x.$$

Comment: Draw a picture!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve the equation
$$
\frac{2}{x} > 3x
$$
we could multiply be $x$ to obtain
$$
2 > 3x^2.
$$
But you have to be careful!
If $x < 0$, the inequality is reversed.
In other words:
$$
\frac{2}{x} > 3x 
\iff \begin{cases}
2 < 3x^2 & x < 0 \\
2 > 3x^2 & x > 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Notice the equation isn't defined for $x = 0$, because you can't divide by $0$.

**Case 1: $x > 0$.**
Then we have
$$
2> 3x^2
\iff x^2 < \frac{2}{3}
\iff x \in \left(- \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3}}, \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3}}\right).
$$
But, since $x > 0$, our first solution interval is $I_1 := \left(0, \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3}}\right)$.

**Case 2: $x < 0$.**
Then we have
$$
2 < 3x^2
\iff x^2 > \frac{3}{2}
\iff x > \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \quad \text{and} \qquad x < -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}
$$
But again, since $x < 0$, our second (and final) solution interval is $I_2 := \left(- \infty, -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$.

So our solution is $I_1 \cup I_2 =\left(- \infty, -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right) \cup \left(0, \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3}}\right)$.

Answer (score 5):

We observe that necessarily $x\neq 0$ whence we can rewrite the inequality as 
$$
\frac{2}{x}-3x>0\iff\frac{2x-3x^3}{x^2}>0\iff 2x-3x^3>0\iff x(2-3x^2)>0
$$
which you can solve.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you're supposed to give some context and explain what you've tried so far.  However, I will take your word that you have been "slowly losing" your mind and give an answer.

Since this is a nonlinear inequality, there is no "cookie cutter" way to solve it.  But you can get an idea of what to do by graphing $y_1=2/x$ and $y_2=3x$, and observing where $y_1>y_2$.

See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vxrmtpstsz) for a graph with $y_1=2/x$ in red and $y_2=3x$ in blue.  Where does the red curve lie above the blue curve?

Well, you can see that there are two intersection points.  But the red lies above the blue from $-\infty$ up to the first intersection point, and then again from zero to the second intersection point.

To find the intersection points, set $2/x=3x$ and solve.

Can you write down the final answer?