# Dealing with an inequality that involves a root on one side

Tags: inequality, roots

I have the following inequality and I would like to get A on it's own:

$$ A \sqrt[q]{\frac{1}{1-q}} \left(\frac {-q}{1-q}\right) ≤ 1 $$

$q$ is just a parameter and $q$ root is like the square root/cube root only for any parameter.

I have tried this so far:

$$ A \sqrt[q]{\frac{1}{1-q}} ≤ \frac {1-q}{-q} $$

But I am unsure on what to do next. Can someone help please.

Comment: What you've done so far is incorrect, or at least incomplete.  You are assuming that ${-q\over1-q}\geq0$  Otherwise, the sense of the inequality will be reversed.  What you've done is okay if you split the problem into two cases.

Comment: @saulspatz My lecturer recently did the following so I was trying to follow the same steps - A * (p/p+1)^p * (1/p+1) ≤ 1 which he solved and got A ≤ (p+1)(p+1/p)^p.

Comment: Was he assuming $p>0?$  An irrational power of a negative number isn't a real number, so he may well have been.  But in your case, if say $0<q<1$ then the root makes sense, but $-q/(1q)<0$ so the multiplication would reverse the sign.

Answer (score 1):

Encouraging you to take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072686/solve-the-inequality-frac2x-3-x/3072691#3072691), I want to draw attention to the fact that you have to be careful about the signs when multiplying or dividing when dealing with inequalities.

**If** $\mathcal{Q} := \sqrt[q]{\frac{1}{1 - q}} \frac{-q}{1 - q} \ge 0$ (this is precisely the case when $q < 0$), you can manipulate your inequality by multiplying by its inverse $\mathcal{Q}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[q]{\frac{1}{1 - q}}} \frac{1 - q}{-q}$:
$$
A
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt[q]{\frac{1}{1 - q}}} \frac{1 - q}{-q}.
$$
If you were dealing with positive $q$, the inequality would be reversed by multiplying with the inverse, because the inverse is then negative as well:
If $\mathcal{Q} < 0$, we have
$$
A 
\ge
\frac{1}{\sqrt[q]{\frac{1}{1 - q}}} \frac{1 - q}{-q}.
$$

**Edit:**
Also, the term $\mathcal{Q}$ can be simplified using $\sqrt[q]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{q}}$ as
$$
\mathcal{Q}
= \left( \frac{1}{q - 1}\right)^{\frac{1}{q + 1}} \cdot (-q)
$$
and therefore its inverse can be stated in a simplified version:
$$
\mathcal{Q}^{-1}
= \frac{1}{-q} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{1 - q}\right)^{\frac{1}{1 - q}}.
$$

Comment: @May, if the answer was of help, please vote it up and/or mark it as the answer.

Comment: @NoChance I did but it gave the notification  'Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: @May, maybe you got to wait :)